# Check if file type exists

Tags: macos, excel, zsh, vba

I am writing a VBA script in Excel for Mac and need to check whether a file type exists in particular directory. I am thought the best way to achieve it was using the MacScript command to invoke a shell script.

```
ScriptToRun = "do shell script ""ls '/path/to/folder/test.txt'"""
MacScript(ScriptToRun)
```

This works but as soon as I put an expansion character into the line it fails. For example:

```
ScriptToRun = "do shell script ""ls '/path/to/folder/*.txt'"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Excel on a Mac, but you should be able to use the [`Dir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx) function, specifying the MacID for the filetype you are after. If it returns a blank string then there are no files of that type in the directory. I.e.

```
If Dir("SomePath", MacID("TEXT")) <> "" Then
  'Do something
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the `Dir` function does not seem to work on a Mac